# Loading a file with XamlServices

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to fix this error. I've tried googling it and cannot find an answer that matches what I am doing. I have no idea on how to fix it. I hope I have a good explanation of my problem below. Can someone please help and explain it to me?

Error Message:

```
Cannot create unknown type 
'{clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib}List    
({clr-namespace:Ventana.Simulator.Support;assembly=Extractor} Message)'.' 
Line number '1' and line position '2'
```

Errors on this line:

```
Message receivedMessages = (Message)XamlServices.Load("Data/ReceivedMessages.xaml");
```

Here is a sample of the file I am trying to load:

```
<List x:TypeArguments="vss:Message" Capacity="32768" 
      xmlns="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"  
      xmlns:vss="clr-namespace:BusinessApp.Simulator.Support;assembly=Extractor"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <vss:Message Address="2" BroadcastByte="120" InteractionID="0"
       IsHandled="False" MessageType="Rx">
  <vss:Message.RawMessage>
   <x:Array Type="x:Byte">
    <x:Byte>120</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>0</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>2</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>4</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>0</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>39</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>254</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>16</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>197</x:Byte>
    <x:Byte>28</x:Byte>
   </x:Array>
  </vss:Message.RawMessage>
  </vss:Message>
</List>
```

Here is a snippett of code I do to save it...from a different application.

```
private static List<Message> receiveMessages = new List<Message>();

// line is populated by a file and this is a sample of what line would have.
string line = "2014-11-26 09:46:56.043\tDEBUG\t11\tSerialPairedExecutable\tRx: 78-F0-02-7F-00-27-    68-1C [EOL]";

const string rxMessage = "Rx: "

message = line.ExtractMessage(line, rxMessage, 3);

string[] array = message.ToArray()[0].Value.Split('-');

int broadcastByte = Convert.ToInt32(array[0].ToString(), 16);

int interactionId = Convert.ToInt32(array[1].ToString(), 16);

int address = Convert.ToInt32(array[2].ToString(), 16);

byte[] bytes = array.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();

receiveMessages.Add(new Message()
{
    BroadcastByte = Convert.ToByte(broadcastByte),
    InteractionID = Convert.ToByte(interactionId),
    Address = Convert.ToByte(address),
    MessageType = MessageType.Rx,
    RawMessage = bytes
});
```

Where the `Message` class is defined as:

```
public class Message : IMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public MessageType MessageType{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] RawMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte BroadcastByte { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte InteractionID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte Address { get; set; }

    public bool IsHandled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I fail to understand why you're using XAML for this instead of regular XML.

Comment: I was told to use it.

Comment: Seems like a terribly bad idea, IMO.

Comment: I don't know enough yet to have an opinion on it. So, no other suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Comment: See [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way) where it shows how to use XamlReader instead of XamlServices, and it also shows how to map namespaces properly before you try to read the XAML, otherwise the XAML reader can't understand your types because there are no namespace mappings.

Comment: Thanks...I will read that and see what I can learn.